# Send Push notification from android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to show push notification in my Android app. I have read online about this Firebase Cloud Messaging (Formerly known as GCM) but can't understand it properly. In every tutorial they are using some sort of console on webpage to send notifications to all users or a particular user. What i want is to send notification automatically when a message is sent to some user(A send message to B and B gets a Notification) not from some console.

Any help?

Comment: you can use a service to notify the recipient a new message has arrived...

Comment: @n00dl3 please tell me in a little detail......

Comment: well I can't, I don't know how your app works ! but if you use a background service to retrieve messages, this service can send a notification using the [`NotificationManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html).
NB: you can also do this from your main activity but the user won't get notifications while the app is not launched

Comment: my app works same as any other application i can send message USER A and when i open and REFRESH my app on other device USER B, I can see the message. but how to set NOTIFICATIONS?

Comment: If you want some help, first elaborate your question a bit : how does your application fetch messages ? HTTP ? XMPP ? raw TCP P2P connection ? are you fetching your messages in the main activity or are you using a [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) ?

Comment: I'm using volley to send and retrieve messages from server.

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications can't go from user to user, i.e. from User A to User B.

The message must go from `User A`, to `your server`, and then from `your server`, to `User B`

Comment: yes I know this mechanism but how to send notification from server to uesr B automatically? then how to notify user B of the message? tutorials shows some sort of console to send notificatons..

Comment: You don't need a server if you can get your hands on the registration ID of the other guy. Server just makes things more convenient usually

Comment: what registration ID are you talking about? the one that GCM/FCM allocate or the unique id that i've in my database?

Comment: the token you get from firebase is called a registration ID

Answer (score 0):

If your messages are not too frequent (like emails, for example), you can build a [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) that will poll messages from the server regularly and display a notification using the [`NotificationManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html).

Otherwise you should stick to Firebase and create a server-side code to interact with the firebase API to notify your users...
Firebase API for servers are explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message).

Sticking with firebase is IMHO the better option...